Is there a way to implement a HTML tag checker just by using stack method?
I've been working on a project to create a simple HTML checker using a stack-based approach, and I've run into some problems. The goal is to check if the HTML tags are properly nested and closed. However, the results seem to be wrong in some cases.
Here's the basic idea behind the function:
Function: 'void checkHTML(const char html)'*
The function reads an HTML string and uses a stack to track opening tags. For each closing tag it finds, it checks if it matches the last opening tag. If there's a mismatch, or if there are unclosed tags left at the end, it should report an error. Otherwise, it should indicate that the HTML is correct.
Here's the relevant code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    char* items[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int top;
} Stack;

void initStack(Stack* s) {
    s->top = -1;
}

int isStackEmpty(Stack* s) {
    return s->top == -1;
}

int isStackFull(Stack* s) {
    return s->top == MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1;
}

void push(Stack* s, const char* item) {
    if (isStackFull(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack overflow\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    s->items[++s->top] = strdup(item);
}

char* pop(Stack* s) {
    if (isStackEmpty(s)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return s->items[s->top--];
}

char* peek(Stack* s) {
    if (isStackEmpty(s)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return s->items[s->top];
}

void freeStack(Stack* s) {
    while (!isStackEmpty(s)) {
        free(pop(s));
    }
}

int isSelfClosingTag(const char* tag) {
    static const char* selfClosingTags[] = {"hr", "br", "img", "input", "meta", "link"};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(selfClosingTags) / sizeof(selfClosingTags[0]); i++) {
        if (strcmp(tag, selfClosingTags[i]) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void checkHTML(const char* html) {
    Stack stack;
    initStack(&stack);

    const char* p = html;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p == '<') {
            const char* tagStart = p + 1;
            const char* tagEnd = strchr(tagStart, '>');
            if (tagEnd == NULL) {
                printf("Error: Invalid tag format\n");
                freeStack(&stack);
                return;
            }

            int tagLength = tagEnd - tagStart;
            char* tag = (char*)malloc(tagLength + 1);
            strncpy(tag, tagStart, tagLength);
            tag[tagLength] = '\0';

            if (tag[0] == '/') {
                // Closing tag
                if (isStackEmpty(&stack)) {
                    printf("Error <%s>\n", tag);
                    free(tag);
                    freeStack(&stack);
                    return;
                }
                char* openTag = pop(&stack);
                if (strcmp(openTag, tag + 1) != 0) {
                    printf("Error <%s>\n", tag);
                    free(openTag);
                    free(tag);
                    freeStack(&stack);
                    return;
                }
                free(openTag);
            } else {
                // Opening tag
                if (!isSelfClosingTag(tag)) {
                    push(&stack, tag);
                }
            }

            free(tag);
            p = tagEnd;
        } else {
            p++;
        }
    }

    // Check for unmatched tags remaining in the stack
    if (isStackEmpty(&stack)) {
        printf("Correct!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Error <%s>\n", peek(&stack));
    }
    freeStack(&stack);
}

int main() {
    char html[1000];

    // Read the HTML input
    printf("Enter HTML code (end with an empty line):\n");
    fgets(html, sizeof(html), stdin);
    html[strcspn(html, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove newline character

    checkHTML(html);

    return 0;
}


I am experiencing some inconsistencies with my HTML checker function. Here are two specific examples demonstrating the problem:

Example 1:

Input:
<html><head><title>Your title here</title></head><body><center><p>Welcome to my styled page!</p></center><hr><h1>This is a header</h1><h2>This is a medium header</h2>This is my first web page<p> This is a new paragraph!</p><p> <b>This is a new paragraph!</b></p></hr></body></html>


Expected Output:
Correct!

Actual Output:
Error 

Issue:
The function reports an error indicating that the </hr> tag is incorrect, while the HTML code is actually well-formed, and all tags are properly closed. The error should not have been reported.



Example 2:

Input:
<html><head><title>Your title here</title></head><body><center><p>Welcome to my styled page!</p></center><hr><h1>This is a header</h1><h2>This is a medium header</h2>This is my first web page<p> This is a new paragraph!</p><p> <b>This is a new paragraph!</b></p></body></html>


Expected Output:
Error 

Actual Output:
Correct!

Issue:
The function incorrectly reports the HTML as correct, while the </hr> tag is missing a matching closing tag <hr>. The error should have been reported.




In both cases, the results are reversed, meaning that the function either falsely reports an error when the HTML is correct, or fails to report an error when the HTML is not properly closed. Can anyone help determine why this is happening and suggest a fix?

I assume you have tried to debug your code? Like using a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens?

As you have defined <hr> as self-closing, it is expected you get these results. Please explain why you think it should ignore the self-closing setting. What do you want to fix? Don't you want <hr> to be self-closing?

Apart from this, HTML is complicated, and not easy to parse. What would happen with this valid HTML: <H1 title="nasty > and <">My problem with the &lt; and &gt; characters</H1>, for instance. There are many other things that can throw off a simple parser. There are real HTML parsers for C, but you need to find one that does the checks you want. Why reinvent the wheel?

Superficial reaction: What about HTML comment blocks? (was asked in a comment).

In my implementation, I initially did not handle self-closing tags correctly, which led to incorrect results in some cases. I understand that self-closing tags like , , etc. should be treated as valid without needing a corresponding closing tag. The problem is that the HTML validator incorrectly flags self-closing tags as errors because it expects each opening tag to have a corresponding closing tag. This is not necessary for self-closing tags.

I want the checker to:
Handle self-closing tags correctly: Ignore self-closing tags when performing matching, since they don't require a closing counterpart.
Provide accurate validation: Ensure that only tags that require closing are validated against the stack, and that self-closing tags are recognized as valid without error.

I wanted to let you know that the issue was indeed related to how self-closing tags were handled. I’ve made adjustments to the code to treat all tags as requiring closing tags, as suggested. This has resolved the problem, and the updated implementation now correctly identifies errors in the HTML-like input.
If anyone has further suggestions or improvements, I’d be happy to hear them
